# How to use BufferedReader when handling massive data

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read massive amount of data(messages) i'm getting from a server which i'm not owning. I'm using a BufferedReader object, with the function readLine() because the messages i'm getting are containing line feed(\n).

1. I have one thread which reads and saves the messages into a message box.
2. I have second thread which polls the messages from the message box(i have 
   thread sync)

This is part of the code of the first thread:

```
      while(!isInterrupted())
      {                 
        if((line = input_reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
           Util.offer_message(message_box, line);
        }
      }
```

I have been told by a support programmer(he works in the company which owns the server) that using readLine() to read messages from the socket, makes me lose data regularly.

Anyway, i can't really verify if i'm losing data or not(because i'm not owning the server).

So my questions are:

1. Is the programmer right about losing data on regularly because of the massive amount of data ?
2. If he does, then how should i handle it ? should i use a function like read(char cbuf[], int off, int len) and then spliting the messages ?

I can supply some more details if needed to understand my problem.

Thx for helping.

Comment: [tag:datainputstream] has nothing to do with this, but [tag:bufferedreader] does.

Comment: @close-voter Too broad? Come off it. It is a very specific question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the programmer right about losing data on regularly because of the massive amount of data?

First, *is* the application losing data? If so, it certainly doesn't happen in this code. If he is telling you not to use `BufferedReader.readLine()` on this pretext he is crazy. Or, shall we say, misinformed. Or perhaps you have misunderstood him.

> If he does, then how should i handle it ? should i use a function like read(char cbuf[], int off, int len) and then spliting the messages?

No. Nothing wrong with `readLine()`. That's exactly what it does, but without the bugs you will build into yours at first.

But I don't see the point of your two threads. I would lose one of them, and the queue, and just read lines directly when you want them.

NB You are ignoring end of stream. If `readLine()` returns null you should exit the loop and close the socket.

Comment: The application lost one message few days ago, so this is why i spoke to him(it has never happened before). It might be a misunderstood. Besides, i  want to understand something. if i'm losing one of my threads and then i'm just reading messages and immediately "handles" them, it won't make the buffer gets an overflow ? because instead of reading all the time new messages and empty this buffer, i'm also spending CPU time to handle the message, and only then i'm reading another one.. Anyway Thx for the last answer and the NB

Comment: What buffer will overflow? If you don't read fast enough, the sender will stall. That's preferable to what will happen with your present code, which is that your internal queue will fill up memory and probably crash the reading thread.